# Не воспроизводится MP3-файл посредством PyQt 5 (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qmediaplayer, qtmultimedia

Я пытаюсь воспроизводить **`MP3`**-файлы, которые лежат в списке. Для этого я передаю методу `play()` путь к композиции(`song`).

Если просто передать его, возникнет ошибка:

> ...
>
> self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
>
> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>
> QUrl(): too many arguments
>
> QUrl(str, mode: QUrl.ParsingMode = QUrl.TolerantMode): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
>
> QUrl(QUrl): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'

Путь в списке является строкой, но что-то все равно не так с типом аргумента. 
Если попытаться *преобразовать аргумент в строку -*

```
self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(str(song))))
```

возникнет другая ошибка:

> DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x80040216 (IDispatch error #22)

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как починить код?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.list = ['1.Papercut.mp3', '13.Numb.mp3']
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()

        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        line = 0
        for song in self.list:
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked = lambda song = song: self.play(song))
            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause')
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)
            line = line + 1

        self.setLayout(self.box)

    # Воспроизведение
    def play(self, song):
        if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl('song')))
        self.player.play()

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()

    # Повтор
    def replay(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В коде есть еще одна проблема. 
Хорошо бы было вынести это в отдельный вопрос, но я даже не представляю его формулировку. 
Сейчас метод `play()` определяет наличие в `player` звука. Если звук отсутствует, задается источник. К сожалению, по такому принципу нельзя организовать работу приложения, проигрывающего несколько композиций, т.к. звук в источнике появится после проигрывания первой песни, и код не будет обращаться к строчке, которая задает путь к композиции. 
Таким образом, будет проигрываться только первая песня. 
Можно ли как-то поправить это, сохранив возможность паузы и продолжения проигрывания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно пишите: `Путь в списке является строкой`, зачем вы его берете в апострофы `'song'` ?

Я отметил строки, в которые внес изменения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

#        self.list = ['1.Papercut.mp3', '13.Numb.mp3']   # Установите свой список
        self.list = ['bibi.mp3', 'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3']

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        line = 0
        for song in self.list:
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))
            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause)
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)
            line = line + 1

        self.setLayout(self.box)

    # Воспроизведение
    def play(self, song):
        print('Yes', type(song), song)                          # Yes
        print('No ', type('song'), 'song')                      # No

# =       if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
# =           self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl('song'))) # No ('song')

        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))         # Yes (song)
        self.player.play()

    # Пауза
    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()

    # Повтор
    def replay(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, видимо, я слишком сильно хотел спать